# using javascript with a string that contains

Tags: javascript, contains

Hi I am currently using java to hide certain tabs and fields on my forms depending on the population of dropdowns, for example here is a code that is working:

```
//Display Transfer tab if it is a transfer application
var ctrlApplicationType = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'ApplicationType');
ctrlApplicationType.on('change', function(e) 
    {

   if (this.getValue() == 2) 
        {
            var tabs = pageObj.getTabs(); tabs.show(2);
        } 
    else 
        {
            var tabs = pageObj.getTabs(); tabs.hide(2);
        }

    }
);
```

In the example above the dropdown is fed from a lookup table and returns the primary key INT, hence ==2 works fine.

However I now have a problem when I am trying to get this to work with a checkbox, because the problem is a checkbox can have multiple options.

My lookup table for checkbox has 5 options, so if i ticked option 1, 2 and 3, the field (string) is stored as 1,2,3.

What I need to do is to do change the above code so it returns true if it contains 1, ie

if (1,2,3) contains 1 then true
if (2,3) contains 1 then false.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: its not java its javascript

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP? Also, Java != JavaScript

Comment: try using a switch statement

Comment: Convert the string into an array and then see if the target value is contained in the array

Comment: ive never worked with javascript so I would appreciate suggested code?

Comment: See [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: ive just seen this, but not sure how to incorporate? var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.includes("world");

Answer (score 0):

Okay, against my better judgement (I'd really like to see you make your own attempt based on the information I've already given you), here you go...

```
var selectedString = "1,2,3"; // from your code, this is this.getValue()

var selectedArray = selectedString.split(","); // split the string into an array using a comma (,) as the split point

var foundInArray = selectedArray.includes('1'); // foundInArray is now a boolean indicating whether or not the value '1' is one of the values in the array.

if(foundInArray)
{
    // do the found action
}
else
{
    // do the not found action
}
```

If you want to compare against integer values instead of string values, that's easy enough too.

```
var integerArray = selectedArray.map(function(x){ return parseInt(x); });

var foundInArray = integerArray.includes(1);
```

Finally, all of this can be chained into a one-liner:

```
if(selectedString.split(",").map(function(x){return parseInt(x);}).includes(1))
{
    // do found action
}
else
{
    // do not found action
}
```

To iterate through a fixed list and show/hide each, you can do this...

```
var possibleTabs = [1,2,3,4,5];

for(n in possibleTabs)
{
    if(selectedString.split(",").map(function(x){return parseInt(x);}).includes(n))
    {
        var tabs = pageObj.getTabs(); tabs.show(n);
    }
    else
    {
        var tabs = pageObj.getTabs(); tabs.hide(n);
    }
}
```

This, of course, assumes that there is a relation between the checkbox value and the tabs. If there's not, then you're going to have to list them all out as individual if/elseif/else statements, and that is going to get out of hand really quickly.

Comment: var ctrlSchemes = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Schemes');
ctrlSchemes.on('change', function(e) 
 {
  var selectedString = this.getValue(); 
  var selectedArray = selectedString.split(","); 
  var foundInArray = selectedArray.includes('1'); 

   if (foundInArray) 
  {
   var tabs = pageObj.getTabs(); tabs.show(4);
  } 
 else 
  {
   var tabs = pageObj.getTabs(); tabs.hide(4);
  }

 }
);

Comment: @JonathanGreen `tabs.hide(4)` Are you wanting to run that when the value '4' is in the selectedString? Or when the value '1' is? The code in my answer is based on "if (1,2,3) contains 1 then true if (2,3) contains 1 then false". If you want to check for '4' instead of '1', then just change `.includes('1')` to `.includes('4')`. Also, do some debugging and make sure that you're actually getting in to the event handler. If you are, log the value of `selectedString` and make sure that it really is what you expect.

Comment: No, the max value it could be is 1,2,3,4,5.  I want to run 5 if codes for each posisble scenario, e.g. if x contains 1, then view tab 1, if x contains 2, then unhide tab 2, and so on

Comment: @JonathanGreen That's a little different from what you asked.  You'll probably want to create an array the contains your list of possible tabs, loop through that list, and then in each iteration put the current number in the `.includes()` call _and_ in your `tabs.show()`/`tabs.hide()` logic

Comment: so if you have a look at the before screenshot http://prntscr.com/gt7d8l you will see that the tab4 (QMS) tab at the top is hidden, when i tick QMS (which is value 1 from the lookup table), it is supposed to unhide tab 4, but see in screenshot, it doesnt...http://prntscr.com/gt7dw5

Comment: Im going to be honest, that is beyond me at the moment, i can handle basic PHP and could probably manage it in PHP, but ive never really used javascript so i need basic :)

Comment: @JonathanGreen I'm sorry, but I can't really teach you JS here. If you really have no idea what you're doing, you're probably better of hiring someone or taking the time to go through some tutorials/lessons and learn. The stuff I've mentioned is not terribly advanced. Also, if there is no logical connection between the checkbox value and the tab, then this is not scaleable at all. You should really rethink that.

Comment: ok well thanks for you help anyway, im pretty sure that code you sent should work, i just need to find out why it isnt!

Comment: just a quick question, if the possible tab ids are 5,6,7,8,9 if i change the ID in the lookup table from 1,2,3,4,5 to 5,6,7,8,9 and create a cross reference, are you saying your map option should work?

Comment: @JonathanGreen Without knowing the nitty-gritty of your application, my first guess would be yes, it should.